# How to correctly use HashMap?

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary, hashmap, key-value

```
HashMap savedStuff = new HashMap();
savedStuff.put("symbol", this.symbol); //this is a string
savedStuff.put("index", this.index); //this is an int
```

gives me the warning:

```
HashMap is a raw type. References to generic type HashMap<K,V> should be parameterized
```

Comment: apache commons Multivalue map may solve your problem.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but since the example you provided uses hard-coded strings to index the data, it seems like you know what data you want to group together. If that's the case, then a Map is probably not a good choice. The better approach would be to make a class out of the commonly grouped data:

```
public class SavedStuff {
  private int index;
  private String symbol;

  public SavedStuff(int index, String symbol) {
    this.index = index;
    this.symbol = symbol;
  }

  public int getIndex() {
    return index;
  }

  public String getSymbol() {
    return symbol;
  }
}
```

This allows your client code to do this:

```
SavedStuff savedStuff = ...
String symbol = savedStuff.getSymbol();
```

Rather than this:

```
Map<String, Object> savedStuff = ...
String symbol = savedStuff.get("symbol");
```

The former example is much less fragile because you're not indexing data with String constants. It also gives you a place to add behavior on top of your grouped data, which makes your code much more object oriented.

Answer (score 8):

```
HashMap<String, Object> savedStuff = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Of course, you will still have to be careful to use the right type when extracting elements.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html) as shown below :

```
Map<String, Object> savedStuff = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `HashMap<String, Object>` is probably the best you can do if you insist on having heterogeneous values in the same map -- you'll need to cast *those* to do anything useful when you retrieve them (and how are you going to know what type to cast them *to*...?), but at least you'll be typesafe with respect to the *keys*.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different Approach:

A Helper class that contains a map and provides different views of it:

```
public class ValueStore {


    /**
     * Inner map to store values.
     */
    private final Map<String,Object> inner = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    /**
     * Returns true if the Value store contains a numeric value for this key.
     */
    public boolean containsIntValue(final String key){
        return this.inner.get(key) instanceof Integer;
    }


    /**
     * Returns true if the Value store contains a String value for this key.
     */
    public boolean containsStringValue(final String key){
        return this.inner.get(key) instanceof String;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the numeric value associated with this key.
     * @return -1 if no such value exists
     */
    public int getAsInt(final String key){
        final Object retrieved = this.inner.get(key);
        return retrieved instanceof Integer ? ((Integer) retrieved).intValue() : -1;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the String value associated with this key.
     * @return null if no such value exists
     */
    public String getAsString(final String key){
        final Object retrieved = this.inner.get(key);
        return retrieved instanceof String ? (String) retrieved : null;
    }

    /**
     * Store a string value.
     */
    public void putAsInt(final String key, final int value){
        this.inner.put(key, Integer.valueOf(value));
    }


    /**
     * Store an int value.
     */
    public void putAsString(final String key, final String value){
        this.inner.put(key, value);
    }

    /**
     * Main method for testing.
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final ValueStore store = new ValueStore();
        final String intKey = "int1";
        final String stringKey = "string1";
        final int intValue = 123;
        final String stringValue = "str";

        store.putAsInt(intKey, intValue);
        store.putAsString(stringKey, stringValue);

        assertTrue(store.containsIntValue(intKey));
        assertTrue(store.containsStringValue(stringKey));
        assertFalse(store.containsIntValue(stringKey));
        assertFalse(store.containsStringValue(intKey));
        assertEquals(123, store.getAsInt(intKey));
        assertEquals(stringValue, store.getAsString(stringKey));
        assertNull(store.getAsString(intKey));
        assertEquals(-1, store.getAsInt(stringKey));
    }

}
```

Before you would retrieve an int value, you would check the value of `store.containsIntValue(intKey)` and before you retrieve a String value, you would check `store.containsStringValue(stringKey)`. That way you would never retrieve values of the wrong type.

(Can of course be extended to support other types as well)