# How to get rid of type warning when using JSONArray and JSONObject

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to create a JSON string piece by piece and by using org.json.simple.JSONArray and org.json.simple.JSONObject. Here's the code.

```
1. JSONObject config = new JSONObject();

2. JSONArray urls = new JSONArray();
3. urls.add("https://www.test1.com/v1");
4. urls.add("https://www.test1.com/v2");

5. config.put("name", "name-test1");
6. config.put("sipUrls", sipUrls);
```

There is Eclipse warning for line 2 and 3:

- type safety: the method add(Object) belongs to the raw type ArrayList. references to generic type should be parameterized.

And warning for line 5 and 6:

- type safety: the method put(object, object) belongs to the raw type HashMap. references to generic type HashMap should be parameterized.

How can I get rid of these warnings?

*P.S.*

The problem addressed here is different from this [How to correctly use HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640648/how-to-correctly-use-hashmap) because there's no way to create a *JSONArray<String>* or *JSONObject<String>*. JSONArray and JSONObject are not parameterizable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly use HashMap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640648/how-to-correctly-use-hashmap)

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArrayBuilder.html

Answer (score 3):

It appears that there's no way to parameterize org.json.simple.JSONArray and org.json.simple.JSONObject by its design. However, you can suppress these warnings by annotation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```