# Correct way to parameterized JSONArray method add

Tags: arrays, json, linkedhashmap

I'm trying to generate a JSON using a LinkedHashMap<String, Object> Object for data and a JSON Array Object to generate the JSON string like this:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> data = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

data.put("SomeKey",Object);
json.add(data);//Here jumps up the warning: (Type safety: The method add(Object) belongs to the raw type ArrayList. References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be parameterized)
/* More Code */
return json.toString();
```

I've tried to get parameterized data adding the next code:

```
json.add((LinkedHashMap<String,Object>)data);
```

but warning remains.

How can I rid of this warning in a good way? Or there's some better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [How to get rid of type warning when using JSONArray and JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43532523/how-to-get-rid-of-type-warning-when-using-jsonarray-and-jsonobject) the only way is to
`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`